# Click on anything but a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have made a dialog that is shown by pressing on a button. I would like to hide it by pressing anywhere else or pressing the escape key. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the dialog on escape key press, just set `closeOnEscape` as `true` in the dialog initializer code. To close the dialog on any click outside of the dialog, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside/2554798#2554798).

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event to the  and in your function do a check. If dialog open, close it.

```
$(body).bind("click", function() {
      if (dialogIsOpen) { // replace dialogIsOpen with your check to see if the dialog is open.
            // code to close dialog
      }
});

$(body).bind("keydown", function() {
      if (keyIsEsc) { // replace keyIsEsc with check for ESC key.
            // code to close dialog
      }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still close it if you clicked on the dialog box?

Comment: You could check the target element when the click bubbles up to the body