# Trigger a jQuery Event Handler Assigned in a Different Code Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a case where a click handler is defined/assigned in one jQuery code block (file) and I want to trigger it from another click event defined/assigned in a different jQuery code block.  How can I accomplish this?

The following code is a greatly simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish. The behavior I want to see is a JavaScript alert "Element One" when I click `#Element2`.

Example HTML:

```
<p id="Element1">Element One</p>
<p id="Element2">Element Two</p>
```

First jQuery code block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Element1').click(function() {
        alert('Element One');
    });
});
```

Second jQuery code block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Element2').click(function() {
        $('#Element1').click();
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE:** My original example actually works. I was building upon my field hint [jQuery UI Dialog solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside), and didn't account for about the ['clickoutside' handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside) that I was using.  Adding a check to for the second element in my 'clickoutside' handler allows the dialog to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger a click when you click on the first element. You can use the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method for this.

```
function element1Hanlder () {
    alert('Element One');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Element1').click(function() {
        alert('Element One');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Element2').click(function() {
        $('#Element1').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: You're assigning the handler to `#Element1` a second time when `#Elment2` is clicked which is not what I am trying to accomplish. I want to trigger the handler that was already assigned.

Comment: @Sonny I read it the other way around. What you need is `trigger`. Updated

Comment: It's still not working for me.  I assume it's a scoping issue because the handler is defined inside the first anonymous `$(document).ready(function() {...});` call, and is not visible in the second anonymous call.

Comment: @sonny the scope shouldn't matter here. You're simply triggering a click on the element. Do you have any other event handlers on it? Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/6VHeP/

Comment: It turns out there was a different issue.  Even my example code works as written.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is based on JohnP's "trigger" suggestion (so you should choose him as the right answer)...

If I load this block from an external js file...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Element1').click(function () {
        alert( $(this).text() );
    });

});
```

Then load this in a script tag within the HTML itself...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Element2').click(function () {
        $('#Element1').trigger('click');
    });

});
```

Seems to be working as intended.

Comment: I'm thinking my reply is too simplified and JohnP's 'trigger' suggestion is the more accurate solution.

Comment: This needs to be two separate `$(document).ready(function() {});` code blocks.

Comment: @Sonny please see my edits. Tested this out and seems to be working.