# Scope between two jQuery blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

There's an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215844/trigger-a-jquery-event-handler-assigned-in-a-different-code-block#6215886) which seems similar, and I imagine this is fairly elementary solution to this problem.

I have some code that I want to separate into two different files (hopefully without setting up Webpack, Parcel or some other modular system.)

I would like jQuery to be available in each file, so have wrapped each in a `jQuery(($) => {});` closure.

However, when I wrap the one with the class I want to instantiate, it's no longer accessible to the code in the other closure:

File one (loads first).

```
jQuery(($) => {
  class someClass {
    constructor(){
      this.hello = $("#hello").html();
    }
  }
});
```

File two

```
jQuery(($) => {
  let some_instance = someClass; # is not defined
});
```

I think maybe I need to assign the first jQuery block to a `const` and bind it to the second one, but haven't figured out how yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can assign the class in the first script to the window

```
jQuery(($) => {
  window.someClass = class someClass {
    constructor(){
      this.hello = $("#hello").html();
    }
  }
});
```

This is irregular, requires global pollution, and is somewhat weird - for something professional, I'd really recommend using Webpack (or some other module bundler) instead if at all possible. It'll make splitting off smaller maintainable modules a whole lot easier, and will permit easy minification/transpilation if desired.

Also note that you need to use `new` and `()` to invoke a class to create an instance.

```
const someInstance = new someClass();
```

(perhaps capitalize `SomeClass` per JS convention)