# jquery 1.4.2 - jquery UI dialog, close when outside click (not modal)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

Using UI dialog.
jquery 1.4.2

I have my code to close a dialog when clicked outside.
This doesn't work for me. However, if I up the version on a local development, it works fine.
The issue is, that I can't up the jquery version for this part of the site.

Thoughts on how to achieve clicking outside a non-modal dialog to close?

```
// Close Pop-in If the user clicks anywhere else on the page
             jQuery('body')
              .bind(
               'click',
               function(e){
            if(
             jQuery('.detailsPopup').dialog('isOpen')
             && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
             && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
            ){
             jQuery('.detailsPopup').dialog('close');
            }
               }
              );
```

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using? You should use the one that works with an ancient jQuery (not sure why you think you can't upgrade though).

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/117/

It is running 1.4.4 but give it a try. Works for `autoOpen` true or false.

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#your-dialog-id').dialog('open');
    closedialog = 0;
});

var closedialog;

function overlayclickclose() {
    if (closedialog) {
        $('#your-dialog-id').dialog('close');
    }
    //set to one because click on dialog (focus) box sets to zero 
    closedialog = 1;
}

$('#your-dialog-id').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        closedialog = 1;
        $(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose);
    },
    focus: function() {
        closedialog = 0;
    },
    close: function() {
        $(document).unbind('click');
    },
    buttons: {
        Submit: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('ui-widget-overlay'))
     {
        $( "#yourDialogId" ).dialog("close");
     }
});
```