# Javascript close dialog if the if the user did click somewhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I open a modal / dialog with JavaScript, how ever when the user clicks on another tab on the same view the modal will still be there and be in the way. So if the user clicks of the modal I would like to close it. But I am not sure how to do it, I know the OnBlur attribute but I haven't come up with a solution that works just yet. 
This is my script:

```
        $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 220,
        width: 305,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Spara': function () {

                if (!validateNumber()) {
                    alert('Procent måste vara mellan 0-100');
                    return false;
                }
                if (!validateProject()) {
                    alert('Du måste välja ett project');
                    return false;
                }
                if (!validateDate()) {
                    return false;
                }

                locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Update/?";

                locstring += '&projectId=' + $('#projectList').val();
                locstring += '&startDate=' + $('#startDate').val();
                locstring += '&endDate=' + $('#endDate').val();
                locstring += '&pct=' + $('#pct').val();

                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid !== "") {
                    locstring += '&id=' + sid;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: locstring,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        reloadTable();
                    }
                });
            },
            'Avbryt': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Ta bort': function () {
                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid != "") {
                    locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Delete/" + sid;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: locstring,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                            reloadTable();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });

    $('#create-user').click(function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        })
        .hover(
            function() {
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            }
        ).mousedown(function() {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
        })
        .mouseup(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
        });

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI dialogs: how to close dialog when click outside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306547/jquery-ui-dialogs-how-to-close-dialog-when-click-outside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a flag called `isShowing` which is set to `true` when the dialog is showing, and attach an event listener to the body or your main container which checks for a click. Then check if the flag `isShowing` is true, if it is `true` then hide the dialog.

**Edit 1**

Another solution,

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog">Some demo text here.</div>
<div>some other demo text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dialog {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != "dialog") {
        document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "none";   
    }
});
```

Here were are comparing the ID of the element clicked and if it does not equal to *dialog* then we hide the dialog.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/1e5vz8vc/

Comment: Thanks a ton for your fast respond.

Comment: It seems to be 1 kind of problem, when it closes it will close everything but it will still leave my 3 buttons that it creates.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson remove all the children of that element to make it work.