# jQuery UI - Close dialog on inpute change outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I close any open jquery-ui dialog if any input change is being made in the **page** outside the open dialog?

I wrote this code:

```
$("input").keyup(function () { 
     $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
});
```

That works fine, but that closes the dialog even if a input change is being made **withing the dialog**, I only need to close the dialog if an input change is being made **in the page, outside the dialog**.

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI - Close Dialog When Clicked Outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside)

Comment: And refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306547/jquery-ui-dialogs-how-to-close-dialog-when-click-outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That close any open jquery dialog on any input change on the page.

```
  $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
  });
```