# Different behaviour of event bubbling for input vs a tag?

Tags: jquery, html, events, propagation

I just realized that different behaviour exists for `<a>` and `<input>` tag.

```
<div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>

<!--<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>-->
<input id="open" value="Open dialog">
```

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});

// Close Pop-in If the user clicks anywhere else on the page
jQuery('html') //set for html for jsfiddle, but should be 'body'
    .bind('click', function(e){
        if (jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
            && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
            && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length)
        {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            alert("close_dialog");
        }
    }
);
```

If using `<a>`, the click event is not propagated to document. If using `<input>`, the click event is bubbled to document, and clicking on the input directly closes the dialog. I know this can be handled with stopPropagation. The question is why `<a>` tags event doesn't bubble up ? Am I missing something ?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hendryH/PRQNY/) to demonstrate. Uncomment the `<a>` and comment the `<input>`, and click on it to see the differences.

Code borrowed from on Jason's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2554779/1645122).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on this line:

```
&& !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
```

You are asking jQuery if the event target is an "a" tag or an element with class ".ui-dialog". Remove the "a" tag in the selector as follows and it should work as you want it to.

```
&& !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog')
```

Here's the modified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PRQNY/1/

P.S: Just to confirm your understanding of events. All events bubble up irrespective of the element tag in the standard DOM event model.

Comment: Okay, got it. `irrespective of the element tag` , yeah I understand, that's why I felt strange and asked this question in the first place. Thanks very much man.!

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the if statement to be false thus you can't see alert which is inside the if statement.

```
&& !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
```

event target is `a` because you clicked on it even though the event has bubbled up.