# Refresh parent page when jQuery UI Dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

So every time a specific dialog box in jQuery UI is closed I want the parent page to be refreshed. How can I achieve this.

jQuery Code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() { 
         var dlg=$('#createTeam').dialog({
         title: 'Create a Team',
         resizable: true,
         autoOpen:false,
         modal: true,
         hide: 'fade',
         width:600,
         height:285
      });


      $('#createTeamLink').click(function(e) {
          dlg.load('admin/addTeam.php');
          e.preventDefault();
          dlg.dialog('open');
      }); 
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<button href="" type="button" id="createTeamLink" class="btn btn-primary custom">Create Team</button>
<div id="createTeam" class="divider"></div>
```

How do I get the main parent page to refresh/reload after the dialog box is closed?

Comment: Is the dialogue a promise?  you could use that and wait for a result before calling a refresh function... What @Bernhard said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the dialogclose event (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close).

```
var dlg=$('#createTeam').dialog({
     title: 'Create a Team',
     resizable: true,
     autoOpen:false,
     modal: true,
     hide: 'fade',
     width:600,
     height:285,
     close: function(event, ui) {
          location.reload();
     }
  });
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. I will accept the answer in 5 mins.

Comment: Do you know how I can close the dialog by clicking outside it?

Comment: Check this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the `reload()` function:

```
window.location.reload();
```

In your code:

```
var dlg=$('#createTeam').dialog({
     title: 'Create a Team',
     resizable: true,
     autoOpen:false,
     modal: true,
     hide: 'fade',
     width:600,
     height:285,
     close: function() {
         window.location.reload();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the dialog, add the [close listener](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close).

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) { window.location.reload(true); }
});
```