# Close UI5 Dialog when clicked outside

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Dialog box somewhere in my application.
When the user clicks outside of the Dialog, I want it to close.
[in JQuery this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside). But in sapUI5 [I cannot get it to work](https://jsbin.com/rifeno/edit?html,js,console,output). Any ideas?

Comment: I also found a link to [SAP help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f1b3856f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm) where this is described. Except, it does not work.

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid closing the Dialog by clicking outside unless it's supported out-of-the-box by UI5. Not only you'd have to deal with internal attributes within DOM manually but also communicate clearly with the user that *that* dialog behaves differently than other dialogs the user has seen before which creates inconsistencies. Instead, use [sap.m.ResponsivePopover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ResponsivePopover) if applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi,

here how I solved it (here is your updated `openDialog()` function. The rest of the code is as it was):

```js
openDialog: function(){
  this._oDialog.open();
  document.addEventListener("click", 
    function closeDialog(oEvent){
    if(oEvent.target.id === "sap-ui-blocklayer-popup"){
      sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--myDialog").close();
      document.removeEventListener("click", closeDialog);
    }
  });
},
```

Here is JSBIN example: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/jinorifime/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

The sap.m.Popover control shows this behaviour by default.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Popover/samples