# jQuery popup div

Tags: jquery

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.data-window').click(function() {

    //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the mask layer the popup closed
$('#mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .data-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
});
```

I have this piece of code which creates popup box with black mask. That part works ok, but what doesn't work is the part where all this should vanish when I click outside the box, on the black mask. Why won't it close?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI - Close Dialog When Clicked Outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside)

Comment: FYI the proper term for what you're describing is a modal or modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the jQuery version you are using. The "live" function is deprecated in the latest version. Try using ["on" function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or ["delegate" function](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of live functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to use .delegate but no success.
I still don't know and can't figure out what exactly is the issue..