# How to submit data and to save the form hidding script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At this [page](https://www.antilopagold.su/suveniry-gorodov/vladivostok/magnit-na-kamne-yaponskoe-more-detail) there is a second orange button under the price called "Заказ в 1 клик". If you click it, input all needed data in the appeared form and then press the blue button "Купить" - you will see that no data is submitted.

Data cann't be submited due to this function:

```
$("#contactForm_oneclick").click( function(){
        return false;
    })
```

which is created to block this function

```
jQuery("#aux").click( function() {//функция, скрывающая форму
            jQuery("#contactForm_oneclick").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#window").fadeOut();
            jQuery("#aux").css("display","none");
            jQuery("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
        } );
```

which is created to hide the form if you click somewhere else then at the form.
How to change this situation and to make the button "Купить" work correctly?

Comment: If you replace your `jQuery("#aux")` event with a click outside event then you won't need the blocking function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI - Close Dialog When Clicked Outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
if I change the handler for the "click" event on $("#contactForm_oneclick") as such:

```
$("#contactForm_oneclick").click( function(e){
    if(e.target.getAttribute('class') != 'addtocart_button') {
        return false;
    }
})
```

everything works fine